# data-test-ids vs user-facing attributes

Tags: playwright-python, e2e

In [this article](https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/playwright-e2e-testing-tips-and-best-practices), and in the official docs of Playwright it is stated that we should prioritize user-facing attributes (like text contents, labels, etc...).
On the other hand, I see people using [data-test-ids](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/other-locators#id-data-testid-data-test-id-data-test-selectors) very often. The questions are,

1. which approach is more preferable? Seems like using user-facing attributes is more efficient because we don't have to do extra work adding data-test-ids to our codebase
2. do they have different use cases ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite close to an opinion-based question. But I can say that user-facing attributes are go-to option, `data-test-ids` can complement some scenarios, For instance, where the label is dynamically generated or changes on every run.

For example, I could think of the label showing the order number created. That number will change on every run, so you won't be able to use it. Also, the aria-label should have the order generated. But you could have a `data-test-id="order-id"` which will be stable.

Comment: What about localization? Because translation strings are scattered among microservices, seems like data-test-ids is the only option in case localization is supported, right?

Comment: Agreed! that would be another use-case. Although, generally speaking, when you are doing E2E testing you tend to know the environment. You know you're testing a website in English.